# Interface Flowchart Examples

Tags: workflow, flowcharts

Looking for examples of "high-end" user interface flowcharts. I've personally designed lots of flowscharts, and created internal standards for them, but it's been years and I'm looking to see what the modern best practices are via real examples.

Comment: What exactly constitutes _high-end_? Lots of shapes? Complicated flow? Pretty graphics?

Comment: I think the best practice (IMHO) is to not make the documentation 'high end' but spend that time building the solution (agile).

Comment: @Aaron Mclver: Good question, though my answer would be that it was clearly made by a professional using a method-based approach; meaning the end-product is a result of a formal system to creating flowcharts, and not something that was produced ad-hoc, or just for fun.

Comment: @DA01: Agree about the agile part, disagree that it's not high-end.

Comment: I'm confused. Agile is certainly high end. I was referring to the wireframes. Wireframes are a sketch much of the time, as they should be. (Outside of UX, on the other hand, flow charts might be highly detailed blueprints, which is a whole other topic)

Comment: @DA01: I see, wasn't clear to me you were stating your preference to exclude flowcharts, and focus on wireframes. I'd say it really depends on the nature of the site. Some sites could easily be spec'd much faster using just a flowchart; though my flowcharts in the past were really mini-wireframes in a way. In the end, I'd say the debate over flowcharts-vs-wireframes is beyond the scope of this question, and the in my opinion there's nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything wrong with your question nor am I debating flowcharts vs. wireframes. I'm simply saying that in terms of 'best practices' I'd say don't spent a lot of time on production documentation (be it wireframes, flow charts, whatever...) But maybe I'm completely misunderstanding your question.

Comment: ack...and I see that I likely confused you by tossing in the 'wireframes' term earlier. Sorry about that. In my above comment replace 'wireframes' with 'flowcharts'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1880/discussion-between-blunders-and-da01)

Comment: Chat doesn't like me (won't let me sign in)

Comment: @DA01: Chat didn't like me either, clicked the link and it auto-posted the comment above. Oh, well, believe we reached an rough agreement anyway - that being, that good prototypes/mockups/outlines rapidly lead to real solutions, and are not just "documentation". Thanks for the input!

Comment: Close. I think quick, iterative, lo-fi sketching of prototypes/mockups/outlines is good. However, taking the time to make those 'high end' is not usually a good use of project timelines, IMHO.

Comment: @DA: Ha, I see, you're still stuck on my use of high-end, which is to mean professional. Using design patterns in the takes time, but that's a trade of to reventing the wheel everytime you start a new project, or take over a project someoneelse startered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a copy of the book [Communicating the User Interface](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119971101). I think it may have the sort of examples you're looking for. You can download a sample chapter for the Kindle.

Comment: +1 @Gordon Kennedy: Agree that the book looks useful, though I'm unable to preview the pages related to the question and not in the habit on spending money to validate an answer. Also, even if by chance I had access to a copy of the book, the value the answer would provide to other users would be limited at best. That said, it's appears to be an on-topic answer, so plus one.

Comment: @blunders The title is Kindle lending-enabled and I'm a helpful guy, so if you drop me an email to the address on my profile then I'll set up the loan.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip, really want that book. It goes through such fundamental aspects to our process and seems to lay out a lot of thinking for you so that you can focus on the thought that goes behind the deliverable instead of the deliverable it self.

Answer (score 2):

You can find many new and innovative flow chart styles at [Jakub Linowski's Wireframes magazine](http://wireframes.linowski.ca/). I've also listed [a new set of diagram styles](http://barnabasnagy.net/category/ideas/) on my website.

Comment: +1 @Barnabas Nagy: Thanks for sharing, though... Neither of your links directly to any information that appears directly related to the question; and as a result, your answer appears as if it might just be spam. Am I missing something? If not, please link directly to the content you believe is of use. Thanks!

Comment: http://barnabasnagy.net/2011/12/26/speech-bubble-user-flow/

Comment: +1 @Barnabas Nagy: Thanks, thought that was the article, though didn't want to assume. Just an FYI, you're able to edit an answer after it's posted, and the answer, not the comments is the first place people will read. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Flowcharts are also covered in ["Communicating Design"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321712463) by Dan M. Brown. The book explains not only how to create them but also how to combine information from different deliverables. A [package of flowchart examples is available](http://www.greenonions.com/communicatingdesign/flowcharts.figures.distro.zip) (zip).

Answer (score -1):

My answer may not serve the purpose, but if you need more info on how UX deliverables can be this is definetely worth Checking
http://cxpartners.com/ux-resources/